# /node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/instructions"' has no exported member 'directive'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on migrating my angular project from Angular 5.2 to Angular 7.2.15 & it's CLI version is 7.3.9. I have resolved almost all issues but one error I am still facing as:

```
/<project_Root>/node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/instructions"' has no exported member 'directive'.
```

I tried to change import statement-

```
import { directive } from '../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/core/src/render3/instructions';
```

to import statement as-

```
import { directive } from '../../../../../../node_modules/@angular/animations/src/render3/instructions';
```

I am unable to find exact path to import directive in Angular 7.2

Answer (score -1):

Isn‘t the Import path for `directive` just `@angular/core`? 
Or do you mean something different? If so where do you want to Import `directive` and what do you want to do with it?